# How do I select an element having a specific child using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume the following html snippet...

**HTML Example**

```
<div class="panel">
    <input type="hidden" class="id" value="1"></input>
    <div class="collection">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" class="id" value="1"></input>
            <input type="text" value="hello world"></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" class="id" value="2"></input>
            <input type="text" value="goodbye moon"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <input type="hidden" class="id" value="2"></input>
    <div class="collection">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" class="id" value="3"></input>
            <input type="text" value="some text"></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" class="id" value="4"></input>
            <input type="text" value="whatever"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I craft a jQuery selector to select the div with class 'panel' where the child element is a hidden input with class 'id' and value of 2?

My current attempt selects the child element, not the parent.  I could just call to get the parent now that I have the child, but I am looking for a selector that gets me the parent the first time around.

**Selector that gets the child...**

```
var element = $(".panel > input[type='hidden'][value='2'].id");
```

I also tried `:has` but it selected both panels because it selects on all descendants, not just the child and div  'colection' has a hidden input with class 'id' and value 2 on the first panel.

Here is my complete testing example...

**Complete Testing Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var element = $(".panel > input[type='hidden'][value='2'].id");
  var elements = $(".panel").has("input[type='hidden'][value='2'].id");
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="panel">
      <input type="hidden" class="id" value="1"></input>
      <div class="collection">
          <div>
              <input type="hidden" class="id" value="1"></input>
              <input type="text" value="hello world"></input>
          </div>
          <div>
              <input type="hidden" class="id" value="2"></input>
              <input type="text" value="goodbye moon"></input>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
      <input type="hidden" class="id" value="2"></input>
      <div class="collection">
          <div>
              <input type="hidden" class="id" value="3"></input>
              <input type="text" value="some text"></input>
          </div>
          <div>
              <input type="hidden" class="id" value="4"></input>
              <input type="text" value="whatever"></input>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you've described by utilizing the [.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method, with the [> direct child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), like so:

`var elements = $(".panel").has("> input[type='hidden'][value='2'].id");`

Working Snippet:

```js
// no-conflict safe shorthand document ready
jQuery(function($) {
  // utilize .has with the > child combinator
  var elements = $(".panel").has("> input[type='hidden'][value='2'].id");
  elements.css({border: '2px solid red'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <input type="hidden" class="id" value="1"></input>
  <div class="collection">
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" class="id" value="1"></input>
      <input type="text" value="hello world"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" class="id" value="2"></input>
      <input type="text" value="goodbye moon"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <input type="hidden" class="id" value="2"></input>
  <div class="collection">
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" class="id" value="3"></input>
      <input type="text" value="some text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" class="id" value="4"></input>
      <input type="text" value="whatever"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that while I think `:has` will work as well, according to [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs-has) `.has()` is slightly faster.

Comment: I awarded this answer because ":has" is slightly slower than".has()" based on jQuery documentation.  They both work.  Something to consider - the :has() may be compatible with a wider browser audience...

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$(".panel:has(> input.id[type=hidden][value=2])");
```

[HERE](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) is the documentation for the `:has(...)` selector.

```js
var $e = $(".panel:has(> input.id[type=hidden][value=2])");
console.log("Number of elements matching the selector:",$e.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
    <input type="hidden" class="id" value="1"></input>
    <div class="collection">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" class="id" value="1"></input>
            <input type="text" value="hello world"></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" class="id" value="2"></input>
            <input type="text" value="goodbye moon"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <input type="hidden" class="id" value="2"></input>
    <div class="collection">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" class="id" value="3"></input>
            <input type="text" value="some text"></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" class="id" value="4"></input>
            <input type="text" value="whatever"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this work in current browsers? I was looking at Moz site and it says it is not supported in any major desktop browsers

Comment: @Huangism - CSS support is not the same as jQuery supporting selectors.  jQuery has supported a variety of css-style selectors long before CSS supported them

Comment: @Huangism Yes it works, [HERE](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) you can find more details about it. Passing `CSS` selectors to **jQuery** is different then using them in a `CSS` file.

Comment: Will this work without quotes around the selector inside the `.has()`?

Comment: @cale_b Yes, it works, I've just tested it. The selector inside `has(...)` doesn't need quotes.

Comment: Awesome.  Learn something new every day.

Comment: according to jQuery docs (https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) the :has() selector has been replaced with .has() for modern browser performance increases.

Comment: @barrypicker It hasn't been replaced, it only says that it is slower then `.has()` in modern browser. This selector still works and it is not marked as *deprecated* which means that it will work in the future.

Comment: @Titus - that is a good point.  Not deprecated, and probably more flexible for a wider audience...

Answer (score 0):

Select the input first, then just get the parent panel:

```
$( 'input.id[type="hidden"][value="2"]' ).parent( '.panel' );
```

The first selector will select both of the matching inputs, the call to `.parent()` with the `.panel` selector will reduce the collection to elements whose immediate parent is `.panel`

If you want it in a single selector, I suppose you could do:

```
$( '.panel:has(> input.id[type="hidden"][value="2"])' )
```

Just bear in mind this is a much less performant selector.

Comment: While this will work, once the html structure changes, it may fail.  I tend to prefer to use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) over `.parent()`.  And, I'm not the drive-by downvoter.... not sure who's doing that.

Comment: Ah, I suspect the downvoter did so because of the OP's statement: _My current attempt selects the child element, not the parent. I could just call to get the parent now that I have the child, but I am looking for a selector that gets me the parent the first time around._

Comment: I didn't downvote either.  I wish a comment would be left if someone downvotes.